# Weblogic 12.1.3 - hibernate lazyload issue

Tags: hibernate, struts, weblogic

recently we upgrade to use Weblogic 12.1.3 and our application with struts/hibernate has started to run into lazyload issue.
We implement the pattern OpenSessionInView to allow to the page to have the hiberate session open.

**Note: with Weblogic 12.1.2 everything works properly.**

Any ideas? anyone with the same issue?

Comment: We can't help debug the issue without knowing anything about the OSIV implementation or anything else about the app, or the exceptions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. If you want to implement the pattern `OpenSessionInView` then use [Full Hibernate Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/full-hibernate-plugin-for-struts2/). If you want to just fix the `LazyInitializationException` use `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` attribute in `@OneToMany` associations.

Comment: The problem is the project I am working on is pretty old and it uses struts 1.

Comment: Did you try option 2 or use OpenSessionInView filter.

Comment: We have a Filter which implement the pattern OpenSessionInView and it works fine on all Weblogic version up to 12.1.2. The big issue is that it does not work on 12.1.3. The application throws a bunch of LazyLoad.. and I don't understand really why...